# How can I improve performance for converting byte[] to int?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm writing a Binary file converter in which I need to convert 1-6 byte arrays into int (short-long) values. At the moment I'm using following three functions, I want to know is there anyway to improve the performance?

```
private string byteToShortParse(byte[] recordData, int offset, int length)
{
    byte[] workingSet = new byte[2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(recordData, offset, workingSet, 0, length);
    return (BitConverter.ToInt16(workingSet, 0).ToString());
}

private string byteToIntParse(byte[] recordData, int offset, int length)
{
    byte[] workingSet = new byte[4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(recordData, offset, workingSet, 0, length);
    return (BitConverter.ToInt32(workingSet, 0).ToString());
}

private string byteToLongParse(byte[] recordData, int offset, int length)
{
    byte[] workingSet = new byte[8];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(recordData, offset, workingSet, 0, length);
    return (BitConverter.ToInt32(workingSet, 0).ToString());
}
```

Comment: If you're dealing with bytes there really isn't much optimization you need to do.

Comment: yes recordData is a bytearray

Comment: This would be a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: oh I didn't know about codeReview website ,can we somehow move the question there ? or tell me what shall I do ? because I was thinking I may not get the answer here .tanks

Comment: Its new, which is why you didn't know about it.  :P

Comment: You're converting a byte[] into an int and then converting the int to a string? That seems like an odd thing to do...

Comment: If `length != 4` for byteToIntParse I think you may get the wrong answer. Did you test this code (before worrying about performance) ?

Comment: @Justin : I need to return string as I'm going to create a csv file     @Henk : yes the code has been tested and is working fine

Comment: @Asha: Off topic, but I think it would be best practice to have these methods return numeric types and `ToString` them afterward. You could reuse your code, for one thing.

Comment: Seems to me you could avoid a large part of the problem by using `BinaryReader`.

Comment: @Jim :would you please explain more what you mean ? now I'm using streamreader to read the file and then extract each record like this :byte[] recordData = new byte[RecordLength];
int noOfReadBytes = fileStream.Read(recordData, 0, RecordLength);
if (noOfReadBytes == RecordLength)
{
   records.Add(recordData);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2:**

I suppose if the number of bytes you need to convert to int is variable length (which does seem strange), I suggest doing it this way:

```
private string bytesToIntParse(byte[] recordData, int offset, int length)
{
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        result |= ((long)recordData[i + offset]) << (i * 8);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Now you have one function, no Buffer.BlockCopy and it supports any length.

**Edit1:**

You could use unsafe code such as:

```
// I don't think you need to specify a length parameter, since int32 is always 4 bytes
private string byteToIntParse(byte[] recordData, int offset, int length)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* p = &recordData[offset])
        {
            // This result will differ on little and big endian architectures.
            return (*(int*)p).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what BitConverter does internally, so I don't think you will gain any performance

Why are you copying the bytes into `workingSet`? You could just:

`return BitConverter.ToInt32(recordData, offset).ToString()`

I guess that yields a performance boost since you don't have to call Buffer.BlockCopy every time :P

Comment: I may have any number of bytes (length) like 3 bytes when bitconverter can't handle it and I must send it 4 bytes , that's why I'm using length and workingset .

Comment: thanks edit 2 is working very good for me , about the variable length that's very common using let's say just 1 byte to present an integer when the range is enough(that's to save on total file size) in fixed record size binary files

Comment: @Asha, What about the performance? Can you share some stats? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, optimal variant would be

```
private string byteToShortParse(byte[] recordData, int offset, int length)
    {
        if (length == 2)
        { 
             short i = (recordData[offset + 1] << 8) | recordData[offset];
             return i.ToString;
        } else return "";

    }
```

The same applies to 4-byte and 8-byte values (just more shifts are needed).

Comment: but as I explained in my comment under Marlon's answer ,I may need to convert just 1 byte or 3 byte or 7 bytes !! so I need to use length and workingset

Comment: @Asha (a) "I explained in my comment" is not the way this site works. If you have something to add to your question -- add it to your question by editing it. (b) and what stops you from creating a set of shortcut methods for common sizes, and use the generic (slow) method for rare cases? Also, even a couple of IFs to cover any possible length (between 1 and 8) will be faster than using BlockCopy which uses unmanaged code.

Comment: This code is doing a big-endian conversion from bytes to a short. BitConverter.ToInt16 uses little-endian conversion. To match the results of the existing code, you'd want to do `(recordData[offset + 1] << 8) | recordData[offset]`, shifting the second byte, not the first.